# jquery ajax .done is not fired but .always is fired

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to attach my jquery code to the 3rd party site, so I'm inserting a button which triggers a request when a page is loaded. An issue I have is that .done callback is not triggered, but .always is got triggered. The only one thing worth to mention is that the page, I try to work with, also makes some ajax request after it's loaded. Could it be a reason why I have the issue?

```
$("<button>Test</button>").click(function(){
  var url="<https url from the site>";
  $.ajax(url).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}).insertBefore("div.top");
```

Comment: that means the ajax request failed for some reason... try to have a fail handler and see what is the reason for failure

Comment: `$.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log(jqXHR, status, error)
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny instead of manually typing all of those arguments, a simple `console.log(arguments)` can save you debugging time! Probably about 5 seconds per argument set, 5*2 = 10 seconds of time.

Comment: @self yes... but I just wanted to be specific and show what are the arguments to OP... also I have a code snippet saved for the fail handler which I copy paste in SO

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you for the idea, I figured out that it's an error **"parseerror" "unexpected token :"**

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added {dataType: "json"} to the call and now all is good! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue with a help from Arun.

There was an error while parsing a response. So after i added an additional parameter {dataType : "json"} to the request, .done is triggered. It looks now like

```
$.ajax(url,{
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data){
    console.log("Success:" + data);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
    console.log("Status: " + status + " Error: " + error);
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `done` function will only be executed if your **ajax** call finish **successfully**, if something went wrong `done` will **never** get triggered.
As its name indicates, the `always` method will **always** get triggered regardless your **ajax** request works or not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I wonder, what could be wrong? I checked the status of the call, and I got 200 and all the data in responseText.

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev can you post your whole code in a fiddle?

Comment: i actually found a problem @ianaya89, see my answer below. Thank you